Azure DNS Create TXT Record Not Inserting Value Property Using Azure REST API
I am trying to create TXT records for domain ownership validation in my Azure DNS zone. I am trying to achieve this programmatically using the Azure REST API.
public async Task<bool> CreateTxtRecord(string domain, string value, string resourceGroup, string dnsZoneName)
{
    try
    {
        var acmeChallengeDomain = $"_acme-challenge.{domain}";
        var endpoint = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/{dnsZoneName}/TXT/{acmeChallengeDomain}?api-version=2018-05-01";


        var requestObject = new DnsTxtRecordRequest
        {
            properties = new DnsTxtRecordRequestProperties
            {
                TTL = 3600,
                TxtRecords = new List<TxtRecords> { 
                    new TxtRecords 
                    { 
                        value = new List<string> { value } 
                    } 
                }
            }
        };

        var serializedRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestObject);
        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, endpoint);
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Token);
        requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(serializedRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Token);
            var responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            var content = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DnsTxtRecordResponse>(content);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                LastError = $"Failed to create TXT record set: {content}";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LastError = $"Failed to create TXT record set: {ex.Message}";
        return false;
    }
}

I have tried to create Req/Res objects that can be serialized and deserialized. Maybe I am getting those wrong? I can not seem to find much specifically on the TXT Records, except for using the .NET SDK. But what happens is, the record is successfully created in the DNS Zone, but the value property is not being set to the value (this is the token obtained from the challenge). Here are my req/res objects that involve TXT Records.
public class TxtRecords
{
    //public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> value { get; set; }
}

public class DnsTxtRecordRequest
{
    public DnsTxtRecordRequestProperties properties { get; set; }
}

public class DnsTxtRecordRequestProperties
{
    public int TTL { get; set; }
    public List<TxtRecords> TxtRecords { get; set; }
}

public class DnsTxtRecordResponse
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string etag { get; set; }
    public DnsTxtRecordResponseProperties properties { get; set; }
}

public class DnsTxtRecordResponseProperties
{
    public string fqdn { get; set; }
    public int TTL { get; set; }
    public List<TxtRecords> TxtRecords { get; set; }
    public object targetResource { get; set; }
    public string provisionState { get; set; }
}

I have tried to insert the value of the newly created TxtRecord as a stand-alone string rather than nested inside of a List. This yielded the same output.
My expectation is for the TXT record to be created in my Azure DNS Zone containing a name, in my case an _acme-challenge, and a value that is the token related to that challenge.
